# date -d not recognizing format %d-%m-%Y

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date

My script should accept 4 date formats: yyyy-mm-dd, yyyy/mm/dd, dd-mm-yyyy, dd/mm/yyyy.

To check if the user supplied date d is valid in any of these formats it does something like this:

```
    if [ "`date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d $d 2>/dev/null`" == "$d" ]
      then
        echo "1"
    elif [ "`date '+%d-%m-%Y' -d $d 2>/dev/null`" == "$d" ]
      then
        echo "2"
    elif [ "`date '+%Y/%m/%d' -d $d 2>/dev/null`" == "$d" ]
      then
        echo "3"
    elif [ "`date '+%d/%m/%Y' -d $d 2>/dev/null`" == "$d" ]
      then
        echo "4"
    else
        echo `date '+%d-%m-%Y' -d $d`
        echo "other"
    fi
```

If I set d to 2018-01-01, 2018/01/01 or 01/01/2018 I get the expected ouput (1, 3 and 4 respectively).

If I use 01-01-2018, however, the output is:

```
date: invalid date `01-01-2018'

other
```

What could the reason be?

Comment: If you are going to be using the `date` function anyway, why not just use it to convert the input date to whatever format you want?  Why restrict the input?  So: `my_date=$( date '+<favorite format string>' -d $2`

Comment: Working with date is difficult,the same happen with a format '%Y/%d/%m' and %d > 12.

Comment: As an aside, `==` isn't guaranteed to work *at all* in `[` (except when you're using the shell-builtin implementation in bash -- if someone runs your script with `sh`, that's no longer true); the only POSIX-defined string comparison operator is `=`.

Answer (score 3):

In [GNU `date`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html), the `+format` specifier indicates the desired *output* format, not how the argument to the `-d` option is going to be parsed.

([BSD `date`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?date) allows you to specify an input format with `-f`, but I guess you are on Linux.)

For guessing an input format, I would suggest something like

```
case $d in
    [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9])
      # assume yyyy-mm-dd
      ;;
    [0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
      # in the civilized world, assume dd/mm/yyyy
      # in the US, assume mm/dd/yyyy
      # in the general case, assume nothing; give up
      ;;
    ... etc ...
esac
```

Notice that there really is no way to know if 4/3 represents the 4th of March or the 3rd of April. Requiring the user to use an unambiguous format, or explicitly indicate how to interpret the format, is the only sane solution.

The features of the `date` command are unrelated to which shell you are using.

Comment: -f don't exist on NetBSD and OpenBSD. On FreeBSD, It's seem you must use it with -j.

Comment: Yeah, BSD `date` is kind of unwieldy. I see `-f` on Mac OS, too; weird that there really a distinct version on [OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/date) and apparently NetBSD!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the numeric date string formats that `date` considers valid are quite restricted. According to [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Calendar-date-items.html#Calendar-date-items), the format "day-month-year" is not included in the accepted formats (**29.2**):

*For numeric months, the ISO 8601 format ‘year-month-day’ is allowed, where year is any positive number, month is a number between 01 and 12, and day is a number between 01 and 31. A leading zero must be present if a number is less than ten. If year is 68 or smaller, then 2000 is added to it; otherwise, if year is less than 100, then 1900 is added to it. The construct ‘month/day/year’, popular in the United States, is accepted. Also ‘month/day’, omitting the year.*

I think that implementing a workaround in your bash script shouldn't be difficult though.